# Applet class not found

Tags: java, html, jsp, applet

I new with applets, and I'm trying to display the applet in my html. (I have installed the plug-in and I'm using Chrome, and i have tried it on IE)

[image]

as you can see the applet class is in the source package and I would like to display it in the page that is in the web pages folder

this is my code:

```
 <applet codebase="/AppletPackage/Applet" code="Applet.class" width=800 height=300>Applet Failed</applet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure your jar file is inside the html file then
Try this:

```
 <applet archive="AppletJarFile.jar"   code="AppletPackage.AppletClassName" width=800 height=300>Applet Failed</applet>
```

On Html5

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" height="400" width="500">
  <param name="code" value="AppletPackage.AppletClassName" />
  <param name="archive" value="AppletJarFile.jar" />
  Applet failed to run.  No Java plug-in was found. </object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<applet  code="Applet" codebase="/AppletPackage" width=800 height=300>Applet Failed</applet>
```

Comment: you don't have .class file in your applet package folder